# How to specifiy schema in JSON document

Tags: jsonschema

Is there a standardized way to specify this documents schema, i have been looking for one, but i am unsure if using the following is the correct way of doing things.

```
// My JSON Document
{
  "$schema": "http://path.to/my/schema.json",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON Schema spec has two recommendations for correlating a JSON document with a schema.  Both have to do with HTTP headers.  JSON Schema does not define a way for JSON documents to be self describing, but it could easily be done in a way similar to the example you gave.

### Content-Type

The `Content-Type` header seems to be the most widely accepted correlation mechanism.  It defines a MIME type parameter called `profile` whose value is a URI to to schema that defines the JSON document.

```
Content-Type: application/json; profile="/my-hyper-schema#"
```

### Link

The other correlation mechanism is to include a `Link` header with a URI to the schema that defines the JSON document.  This `Link` should have a `rel` of `describedBy`

```
Link: </my-hyper-schema#>; rel="describedBy"
```

### Reference

- http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor33